# No Module named setup tools, but I have it installed.

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, setuptools

When I try and install BeautifulSoup I get this error.

```
> C:\Users\Dylan>python -m pip install beautifulsoup Collecting
> beautifulsoup   Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/ee/295988deca1a5a7accd783d0dfe14524867e31abb05b6c0eeceee49c759d/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
>     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools' C:\Users\Dylan>python -m pip install beautifulsoup Collecting
> beautifulsoup   Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/ee/295988deca1a5a7accd783d0dfe14524867e31abb05b6c0eeceee49c759d/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
>     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
> 
>     ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
> C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5eu92g3l\beautifulsoup\
```

I have tried uninstalling setuptools and reinstalling. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of python do you have installed, and what version of pip do you have installed?

Comment: @DylanAirhart do you have multiple Pythons installed? Working on Windows, you may want to remove your Python installations and install Anaconda. It has a dead simple installer (.exe) and will make life *lots* easier for you as you get deeper into Python. If you uninstall all your Python versions then install Anaconda and use pip without the `python -m` prefix, life should be good...

Comment: @duhaime I have python 3.7 installed and anaconda, is that the issue? Should I uninstall both and do a fresh install of anaconda?

Comment: @SPYBUG96 Python 3.7 and anaconda with python 3.4. pip is 10.1 I believe, I just installed it and updated it.

Comment: @DylanAirhart yes, I'd uninstall all Python versions and (re)install Anaconda if I were in your shoes. Anaconda will make it *much* easier to install libraries like numpy and scipy, should you need to do so in the future. I'd upgrade now; it will save lots of time.

Comment: @duhaime Gracias! You have broken my stackoverflow cherry.

Comment: @DylanAirhart oh my word. Welcome!